# What constitutes a quantum database?

Tags: architecture, terminology-and-notation, technologies

Newb question, I know it's broad. I'm coming here for validated pointers, so I can know what to read. I have QT for CS (Yanofsky, Mannucci) and am reading about Shannon and Von Neumann entropy, but I'm still not sure what we mean when we say a quantum database.  My understanding that all models are Turing reducible, so does it matter what medium a quantum database is in?

- What do we mean by quantum database?

Search for tags here shows no database tag, which gives me a little information, but google still feels not reliable for a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

It is a very interesting question. Quantum database would be a correlated collection of entangled ensembles of quantum data structures such as bloom filters, quantum graphs and quantum time series data distributed over quantum stream schema governed by Quantum Turing Machines and Quantum Fields as defined by David Deutsch, Richard Feymann, Yuri Mann among others. At this moment, this kind of a concept may sound very vague and vividly imaginative. However this is quite doable as researches have already realized quantum bloom filters and quantum gauge graphs using baseline algorithms like Grover Algorithm, [Bernstein-Vazirani Algorithm](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/bernstein-vazirani.html) Algorithm and [Simon Algorithm](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/simon.html) in IBM Qiskit. Hence [Quantum Time Series Databases](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217732318502085) and [Quantum Graph Databases](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00765.pdf) would be an easier construction than Quantum Correlational Databases with stronger and secure entanglements.

Please refer to the following articles for further facts.

1. [Quantum Bloom Filters and its applications](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9336250/)
2. [Quantum Ensemble Encoding using Bloom Filters](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-96770-1)

Comment: Is it correct to say that "for a truly quantum database, it must be able to express quantum properties such as genuinely random number generation, multiple parallel operations in a single register, and perfectly simulate physical systems with finite-dimensional state spaces."  (Extending Yanofsky, Mannucci, *Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists*, Appendix A.2)  Does "physical systems" mean real "real" space with real numbers?

Comment: I really appreciate those links to freely available research :) :) :) they look like *exactly* what I need for formal question.  Yanofsky/Mannucci recommend reading: Feynman (1982), Benihoff (1982), Deutsche (1985,1989), Yao (1993), & Bernstein/Vazriani (1997) for quantum computing models in general.

Comment: Yes. It is quite true that Quantum Randomness would play a pivotal rule in the construction of Quantum Correlations based Relational Databases in the near future. Quantum Randomness would help us to establish Hash Pointer based Indexes for Quantum DB as outlined in recent papers published in Research Gate. It is worth noting that these hash functions would be highly asymptotic. https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/688.pdf